# How to print time in "dd mm yyyy hh mm sec" format in LINUX / C

Tags: c, linux, datetime

I am generating an XML file using libxml2. In one of the tags i want to put the current time in `"dd mm yyyy hh mm sec"` format. 
My dev environment is C/LINUX.
Thanks !

Comment: i've tried time(NULL) but it is giving the number of seconds since 1 jan 1970. I am new to C/LINUX, i dont exactly know how to manipulate the seconds to get the needed format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strftime`. Check the manual page for details.